# The best way to use Foreign Keys(FK)

Tags: mysql, database, yii, relational-database

I am just a newbie to the beautiful Yii framework. I was just going through the documents and one doubt came to my mind.I want to know is it good to define Foreign Keys(FK) in the database when we are creating a database or is it good to declare a foreign key inside an application's code.Any suggestions and comments are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Create them in the database. Yii will automatically generate ActiveRecord classes for you, with the relations. See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr